# Admob with flutter show only same one video

Tags: flutter

Hello I publish flutter app with admob package, but I have always the same video when I push button for reward ad. I'm not expert in ad's but I think it doesn’t pay me much to always have the same video, maybe not all. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are seeing only one ad over and over again that's upto google. Your app can be fairly new so it takes time for your application to get different ads. AdMob uses an ad auction to automatically select the ads that will appear on your application.